# Враги заходят в друг друга unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я начинаю убегать от врагов(у меня отвечает отдельный скрипт за их спавн), они как-бы сливаются друг с другом и в итоге все находятся в одном враге(то есть может показаться что там не 5 врагов, а 1). Возможно это связанно с transform, но я не знаю.

Код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float seeDistance = 2f;
    public float attackDistance = 2f;
    public float speed;
    float speed2;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    Transform target;
    public GameObject deathEffect;

    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
        speed2 = speed;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!die)
        {
            Target();
            FollowPlayer();
        }
    }


    private void Target()
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            Start();
        }
    }
    private void FollowPlayer()
    {
        var dir = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.velocity = dir * speed;
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) <= seeDistance && Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > attackDistance)
        {
            speed = speed2;
            EnemyFlip();
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) <= attackDistance)
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
        if (Hp == 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    private bool horizontalMove = true;
    private void EnemyFlip()
    {
        if (target.transform.position.x > gameObject.transform.position.x && !horizontalMove)
        {
            horizontalMove = !horizontalMove;
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
        else if (target.transform.position.x < gameObject.transform.position.x && horizontalMove)
        {
            horizontalMove = !horizontalMove;
            Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
            theScale.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = theScale;
        }
    }

    public int Hp;

    bool die = false;
    private void Die()
    {
        die = true;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        if (theScale.x > 0)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
        }
        else if (theScale.x < 0)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 270);
        }
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
        speed = 0;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Hp -= damage;
    }

    private float timeAttack;
    public float startTimeAttack;
    public int damage;
    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (timeAttack <= 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                timeAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итог: если у кого-то будет такая же проблема, то просто отключите freeze position и включайте в случае крайней необходимости :)

Answer (score 1):

Если игра Top-Down: Добавь врагам Collider и Rigidbody2D, отключи в Rigidbody2D использование гравитации, и включи FreezeRotation, а если игра платформер: Добавь врагам Collider и Rigidbody2D

Comment: Именно ответ мне не помог, но благодаря нему я додумался отключить freeze position и теперь все работает :)